# I cant uninstall a program, neither install, what to do?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a program (Office 2010) but somehow it all was deleted from its "program files" folder.

If I try to reinstall: installer crashes, and no usable message

If I try to uninstall: Windows 7 was unable to do the uninstalling.

Now what?

Comment: While trying to reinstall, exactly what happens when the installer "crashes"?  Anything in the Application or System Event Logs? Which version of Office 2010 are you using?

Comment: Windows just say "application crashed and Windows is looking for the solution". Where are those logs? I never used any of them

Comment: Event Logs: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7

Comment: "The Office 64 Source Engine service is disabled" mightbe it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to uninstall, I have found IOBIT uninstaller will uninstall programs that windows will not. I have used it multiple times. Here is a link [IOBIT uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)